# Docker: Access a service on host from a container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, containers, devops

I need to access a service running on host machine from a docker container using docker-compose setup file.

Plus at this point I do not know if I will be able to change hostname that app in the container uses so service must be available on 'localhost' host.

I know how to do it with `docker run`: `docker run --net="host" ...` - it works exactly as I need: for example i can `wget http://localhost` from the container and I will receive a file served by host's web server.

What I do not know is how to configure same thing in `docker-compose.yml`

I tried this

```
version: '3'

services:

  nginx:
    container_name: cont
    image: ubuntu
    command: sleep 10000000
    networks:
      - host

networks:
  host:
```

But was not able to reproduce same functionality.
How do I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) documentation you should use `network_mode: "host"` statement.

The final `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: cont
    image: ubuntu
    command: sleep 10000000
    network_mode: "host"
```

Comment: Thank you! It is the right answer. Even though I will not be able to use it because it does not work as I would expect on mac: For a Mac "host" is VM used to run docker, not mac itself, and that is where my application that I need to access is running. Please, let me know If you know how to access host Mac. Thanks!

Comment: Use `host.docker.internal`. This should do exactly what you would want on the Mac.